# Tagging s3 objects written with glueContext.write_dynamic_frame

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue ETL jobs to ingest some datasets using their PySpark API; namely loading a `DynamicFrame` from S3 objects, doing some transformations and finally writing the results in some S3 location (using `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options`) or a catalog (using `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog`).

To keep things organized, we have policies that prevent object creation in the target locations if they are not tagged properly.

I am wondering if there is a way to tag the s3 objects that are created as part of the write process.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Glue APIs. You may have to use S3 Boto library to add tags.

Comment: We figured that talking to AWS folks. Thanks!